# Why does $f = u+iv$ holomorphic $\implies$ $-if = -iu + v$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we multiply both sides of a holomorphic complex-valued function $f = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ by $-i$, why is it true that the resulting equation is also holomorphic?

Comment: Have you multiplied by $-i$ or $-iv$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(z) = -iz$. $g$ is just multiplication by a constant and therefore holomorphic. 
$g(f(z))=-iu+v$ must be holomorphic because the composition of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

Comment: $-i$ is considered a constant?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs What else?

Comment: I thought it's an imaginary number and that constants are only real numbers

Comment: No, complex numbers are constants as well. By virtue of just doing complex analysis we've tacitly agreed that our constants are the complex numbers.

Comment: Like real constants, there are also imaginray and complex constants

Answer (score 3):

Because (complex) differentiation is a linear operation (over $\mathbf{C}$), so if $f$ is (complex) differentiable (i.e. holomorphic), then so is $\alpha f$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbf{C}$ (i.e. $\alpha f$ is also holomorphic). Your question consider $\alpha=-i$.

**Edit**
If we denote complex differentiation by $'$, then linearity of $'$ is stated by the properties
$$
(f+g)'=f'+g'\quad\text{and}\quad(\alpha f)'=\alpha f'
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary differentiable functions and $\alpha\in\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: this is a greedy answer. I like it, but, perhaps he ought to think about the CR-equations for the original function in comparison to the new multiplied function.

Comment: What is a linear operator?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook It was not my intention to offend anyone, so if I did that, I truly apologize. I just think this is a good way of thinking of it. (But now that I read OPs question on my answer, I realize it was maybe not so good...)

Comment: I am not offended! This answer is a great answer. You capture complex differentiability in an elegant manner. My answer uses the less sophsticated CR-equation perspective which is sometimes all that is taught in the intro course. I like your answer, no offense!

Comment: When I really thought about this, it makes a lot of sense. Pretty good answer

Answer (score 0):

Because the product of two holomorphic function is holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f=u+iv$ if $f$ is holomorphic then $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. Consider $g=-if=-v-iu$. Notive $(-v)_x = (-u)_y$ and $(-v)_y = -(-u)_x$ by application of the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f$. Furthermore as $f$ is holomorphic we know $u,v$ and by extension $-u,-v$ are continuously differentiable hence $g$ is holomorphic on the same domain on which $f$ was holomorphic.